# Starting diesel car on low battery

Tags: battery, starting

I am going to try starting my car after long time standing in the street (month). I know batter will be in poor condition. What is my best chance to start the car? My car has some sort of engine preheat function that is supposed to heat the engine a little before starting. Given the battery state should I try to start it as soon as possible let this preheat cycle run once or run the cycle multiple times? Thanks. Car is Toyota Avensis 2009.

Comment: "What is my best chance to start the car? " charge the battery.

Comment: you should definitely hook up a trickle charger. Buy a battery tender - it is a great investment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the battery is bad you change the battery before you try to start the car.

A bad battery will not get better by standing for a month,it is most likely more damaged now than it was when you parked the car.

That beeing said if the battery was in fair condition when you parked,it might be possible to charge it,You will need to take the battery out of your car and bring it inside so it can warm up a bit while you charge it.

If you start your car while the battery is at room temparature you will get the max power for starting your car,use the preheat before you try to start,it uses some power but the chances your engine starts is better.

Do not run the pre heat cyclus more than 2-3  times if your car does not start.